# Multiple RadioButtons slowing down others inputs in form

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I created a cshtml page with a "foreach" function creating table cells with radio button on each one...
At the end, it creates a table with almost 150 cells. The problem is, when I put radiobutton inputs in the cells, the other inputs of the page turn down very slow... Like text input lagging a lot when typing in it...
If there is no radiobutton inputs, other inputs work well

Is there a way to improve that?

Here is the code:

```
   <table>
   <tr>
    @{var counter = 1; }
    @foreach (var i in filesListing) {
    {
        var vi = i.Substring(27);
        var vi2 = i.Substring(35);
        <td style="border:1px solid black; vertical-align:text-bottom">
        <img src="../../../@vi2" width="50px"><br><p style="text-align:center;"><input type="radio" name="icone" value="@vi"></p>
        </td>
        if(counter%5 == 0)
         {
             @:</tr><tr>
         }
        counter++;
      }
    }
   </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: I dont see there is any improvement can be done beside reduce the records return instead of 1 chunk of data, try break it into paging

Comment: I'm using a Form with others inputs, I don't wan't the already filled inputs to be erased with a page reload... Is there a way to do that??? I tryed with JQUERY pagination, but others inputs were still slow.